# PyCharm: Recording Mouse and Keyboard to then repeat them multiple time

Tags: pycharm

I want to create a script for pycharm that funtions similarly to a macro. In the first phase I want it to record all of my keyboard and mouse events and movements. This includes dragging, copying and pasting, and the xy coordinates of all movements and events around the screen .
Then, after hitting a hot key - "9" for example - I want it to stop recording and transition to repeating that pattern, inclduing the timing, on a loop.

For the life of me I can not figure out how to do it, and my poor attempt at problem solving has muddled my code so that I don't even know what it's doing anymore and it is not worth sharing. (but I did below) This is my first time coding in python and it is not going well.

Below is the current iteration of my code, it is very broken.

```
import time
import threading
from queue import Queue
import pygetwindow as gw
import keyboard

# Global variables
events = []
recording = True

def record_events(event_queue):
    global events, recording

    while recording:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('9'):
            recording = False
        else:
            for win in gw.getAllWindows():
                if win.isActive:
                    events.append(('mouse', time.time(), win.getMousePosition()))

def main():
    global events, recording

    event_queue = Queue()

    # Record events
    record_thread = threading.Thread(target=record_events, args=(event_queue,))
    record_thread.start()
    record_thread.join()

    # Dialog box for repetitions
    repetitions = int(input("Enter the number of times you want to repeat the pattern:"))

    # Replay events
    if repetitions is not None:
        for _ in range(repetitions):
            prev_timestamp = None
            for event in events:
                event_type, timestamp, event_data = event

                if prev_timestamp is not None:
                    time.sleep(timestamp - prev_timestamp)

                prev_timestamp = timestamp

                if event_type == 'mouse':
                    pyautogui.moveTo(event_data[0], event_data[1])
                    pyautogui.click()
                elif event_type == 'keyboard':
                    keyboard.write(event_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```